# smartgit - how to view and copy to clipboard the repository url for cloned repo?

Tags: smartgit

I use the smartgit [v6](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation/6/).

How to view and copy to clipboard the repository url for cloned repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the repo, go to `Remote/Properties` or `Remote/Edit URL`.

Comment: in v6 it's `Remote\Edit URL`. Thank you.

Comment: I was trying to edit the answer myself, that's why your edit was automatically rejected, sorry.